# matplotlib - strange y-axis when plotting multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science

Why does this piece of code create such a strange output?

I want the plots to overlap so that I can see overlapping data points.

It seems that the plots are stacked on top of each other.

```
def read_csv(name):
    file = open(folder+name,newline='')
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter=";")
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(np.array(row[5:]))
    file.close()
    return data


def setup_plotting():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
    return ax


acc_x = read_csv("acc_x.csv")

ax=setup_plotting()

for entry in acc_x:
    ax.plot(entry)
```

[image]

Please help me :)

Comment: what happens if you comment out the `set_major_locator` lines?

Comment: the same plot but with so many different values that you cannot read anything on the y-axis

Comment: can you edit your post and give an example `acc_x` so I can test it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) returns text, and therefore the plot does not order the values.
You should convert the values with `int` or `float`:

```
for row in reader:
        data.append(np.array([int(x) for x in row[5:]]))
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't see that one :)